# Your suggestions on how to manage data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 58207 x 6. It is produced as a result of different combination of values. Using tidyverse I have grouped by the first column and used do() to assign each unique 1st column value to its specific dataframe from column 3 to 6. However, I cannot figure out how to do the same for column 2 with the difference that I only need unique values stored in a list and not the repeats.

Here is the head of the data frame.

```
# A tibble: 58,207 x 6
   id       pfam   go_id   name                nmspace     linkage_type
   <chr>    <fct>  <fct>   <fct>                <fct>           <fct>
 1 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ cytoplasm            cellular_compo~ IEA
 2 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ cytosol              cellular_compo~ IDA
 3 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ plasma membrane      cellular_compo~ IDA
 4 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ nuclear chromatin    cellular_compo~ IDA
 5 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ apoptotic process    biological_pro~ IEA
 6 O00273_~ PF020~ GO:000~ protein binding      molecular_func~ IPI
```

Any suggestions on how to get the levels() value for each group_by(id) on the second column and storing the to a list corresponding to the id would be appreciated.

And I am new in this. If you have any suggestions on how to handle data such as this please do let me know. Basically I'm hoping to do comparisons between different IDs after.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ok for you?

```
# dummy data, using data.table package, converting from tibble
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
library(gtools)
df <- tibble(id = rep(c("id1", "id2", "id3"), each=3),
             X1 = c("a", "f", "b",
                    "b", "a", "e",
                    "a", "f", "f"))
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[]

# retaining data structure
out1 <- dt[, .(unique.X1 = unique(X1)), by = id]
out1[]
# as a list
out2 <- dt[, .(unique.X1 = list(unique(X1))), by = id]
out2[]

# back to original format
out2.df <- as.tibble(out2)
out2.df

# EDIT: getting unique combinations
ids <- unique(df$id)
lookup <- as.data.table(gtools::combinations(length(ids), 2))
lookup[, V1 := ids[lookup$V1]][, V2 := ids[lookup$V2]]
setnames(lookup, c("V1", "V2"), c("ID1", "ID2"))
lookup[, index := .I]
setkey(dt, id)
joined <- lookup[, .(intersect = list(intersect(dt[J(ID1), X1], dt[J(ID2), X1]))), by=index]
out <- merge(joined, lookup, by="index")
out[, index := NULL]
out[]
```

Comment: Yea, I just came to the same conclusion using unique. Thank you for your time. In your opinion is this the right way to manage data? Later I am using Reduce() to get the intersections between IDs.

Comment: You have an input of 2 ids, and you want to get the intersect of `pfam` between these ids? e.g. if id1 has `pfam=c(1,2,3)` and id2 has `pfam=c(3,4,5)` the `function(id1, id2){...}` would return the intersect, ie `c(3)`? ie `Reduce(intersect, list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5)))`

Comment: I've edited my response to include a way of getting all intersections of a variable

Comment: Yea, but it is not always two IDs, sometimes it is more up to 50. The code for getting the intersection between multiple entries seems fine as I have tried it before with the column 3 to 6 collapsed into a dataframe. Thank you again. Complete code.